# Checking the validation of Regular expression validator in C# back end

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, ado.net

```
protected void UserId_TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select user_id from Userinfo where user_id='" + UserId_TextBox.Text + "@femail.com'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        UserId_Label.Text = "Someone already has that username, try another?";
    }
    else 
    {
        UserId_Label.Text = "Wow , its a unique username! please fill in the remaining fields of the form";
    }
```

This is a piece of code I'm using for checking if a user already exist or not, I want to check before the control goes to the else part of the loop that the regular expression validator which I've imposed on the textbox is validated or not... can someone please help in here. (Can I use else if statement before else part and check if regular expression has been validated by some method?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate the textbox regularexpression validation on the else with an ifelse

```
 if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    UserId_Label.Text = "Someone already has that username, try another?";
}
elseif(!Page.IsValid)
{
    // Do what needs to be done when not valid
    UserId_Label.Text = "Invalid username input";
}
else
{
    UserId_Label.Text = "Wow , its a unique username! please fill in the remaining fields of the form";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Page.IsValid` to determine if all of the validators are passing, like this:

```
else 
{
    if(Page.IsValid)
    {
        UserId_Label.Text = "Wow , its a unique username! please fill in the remaining fields of the form";
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something here, because validation failed
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sunny - no problem, if you feel my answer helped you, then please accept the answer and up-vote the answer when you can. :-)

Comment: i'll surely do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way by Page.IsValid:

```
if (Page.IsValid && Regex.IsMatch(stringtomatch,@"RegularExpression")
{
}
```